# What is a Module?

Tags: magento2, module

I'm learning about Magento 2 and am curious about the term "module" and how it relates to Magento. What exactly is a module, both in general terms and specifically?

If I understand correctly, a module can be a:

- Theme
- Child theme
- Extension
- Other modification

Am I right? Also, am I missing anything? What else can a module be?

Comment: Theme is a Magento2 component which provides the look and feel of store front / backend. And Theme is not a module. But inside a Magento module you can override or extend the other module's templates or layouts or look and feel.

Comment: Extension - it can be a Magento2 module if it alters / extends the behavior of Magento2 core modules.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento2 module is one of the components which provides a certain feature / functionality. For an example, module-checkout provides checkout functionality in the store front. Similarly each module has it's own features and and they can also be dependent on other modules.  I insist you to go through [Magento 2 official docs for proper knowledge](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/bk-extension-dev-guide.html)

[Magento Modules Overview](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_intro.html)

[Modules and Areas](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_and_areas.html)

[Module Conventions](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_conventions.html)

[Module Relationships](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_relationships.html)

[Module dependencies](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_depend.html)

[Module dependency types](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_depend_types.html)